# Print files with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing

I need to print some files dynamically using javascript and iframes. The files list came as response of an AJAX call. I can't avoid having this error:

```
_SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object_
```

from the browser. This is part of my code:

```
$('.js-print_box').html('<iframe class="js-print_frame" name="iprint" src="print?' + params.join('&') + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="0" height="0"></iframe>');

$('.js-print_box').append(data.preplanFilesContent);

var iframeEls = document.querySelectorAll('.js-print_frame');
if (iframeEls) {
  for (i = 0; i < iframeEls.length; i++) {
    iframeEl = iframeEls[i];
    $(iframeEl).load(function() {
       var result = iframeEl.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
       if (!result) {
         iframeEl.contentWindow.print();
       }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace dynamic iframes for

```
<object data="https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/44678.pdf" type="application/pdf">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/44678.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

See the code here
`https://jsfiddle.net/zwdq69q0/`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to modify and access other websites that are in iframe's because of the "Same-Origin Policy." If you're using an MVC of some sort, there may be configuration where you can allow the origin that is requesting the iframe.

This is implemented to prevent [Cross-site Scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

This is a server-side issue. You need to find out whether or not you can edit configuration on the server-side to allow the origin loading the iframe.

You need to make it so the preflight request when you make a request returns as a HTTP 200 status code.

If you look in your network tab, your preflight request is probably failing. The server of the iframe's origin needs to accept an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header along with the origin of the request (your page), as an acceptable origin for cross site requests.

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

[CORS Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Taking some time to read about the topics might give you a better understanding of how these technologies work!

Comment: Thanks for asking. I read those documents, but I can't figure it out where do I need to set up those headers. On the AJAX url? On the view? I'm using Yii, and files that I need to print are on the same server the web app is

Comment: I believe this is what you need. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53185-implementing-cross-origin-resource-sharing-support-in-your-yii-framework-application/. This should be a server-side configuration. Meaning it should be in the Yii configuration code. There should be a Cors class you can use as middleware in the Yii framework that would allow this. Even if its on the same server, make sure they're same protocol, same host, same domain!

Comment: I've never used the Yii framework so I can't be of too much help in regards to specifics.